# Проблемы с git после пуша изменений

Tags: git

есть сервер, на который я пушу изменения.
Работаю на МАК оси, после того, как пушу изменения, на сервере появляются **Changes to be committed:**, которая откатывает версию проекта далеко назад, такая ситуация абсолютно после каждого пуша.

После пуша я делаю `git reset --hard developer` и только после этого делаю `pull` - и получаю свою актуальную версию.

Проблема может быть в правах? Сталкивался кто с подобным?

Comment: Мало что понятно, в частности, непонятно, что за "changes to be commited" на сервере. В репозитории не может быть никаких changes to be commited. Опишите подробнее что делаете и что происходит..

Comment: @Эникейщик Пушу изменения через PhpStorm на сервер, на сервере захожу по ссш и делаю git status, получаю следующее - http://joxi.ru/L21Zz9YHRGvWQA

Comment: Куда вы заходите на сервере по ssh? И зачем?

Comment: у вас по какой-то причине на сервере обновляются эти файлы, по какой, сложно сказать.

Comment: и производить изменения от рута, не совсем есть хорошо

Comment: `git diff` посмотрите что за изменения, думаю так будет яснее

Comment: @Эникейщик в смысле зачем? Чтобы спулить изменения на сервере, которые я запушил в репу с локала.

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov, там старые версии файлов, проект как будто откатывается назад на какой-то промежуток времени

Comment: Аа, так у вас сервер это как еще один пользователь, я думал, вы репозиторий так называете. Тогда да, там изменяются файлы, нужно смотреть кем, чем и почему.

Comment: @manowartop так нужно выяснить почему откатывается, кто их правит. Само по себе, ведь это не может работать))

Comment: @Эникейщик они изменяются сразу после моего пуша с локального сервера. Работаю с репой только я

Comment: Время/часовой пояс везде правильно стоят?

Comment: На сервере другой часовой пояс. 
Заказчик из другой страны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышел из положения склонировав проект заново и заменив папку .git старой копии новой.

Видимо было что-то с файлами в папке.